# Does Immunity/Resistance to a type of damage count as Damage Reduction?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, immunities, damage-reduction

Does Immunity to a type of damage or Resistance to a type of damage count as Damage Reduction?

Answer (score 3):

## No

Damage Reduction is a specific thing with its own specific rules.  It never (unless you are playing with the change in *Complete Psionic* as opposed to the PHB) applies to damage from spells (even non-energy damage) nor energy damage (even from non-spells), for example, whereas Immunity and Resistance apply even to magical threats. So, while e.g. Energy Resistance *does* reduce incoming damage of a particular type or from a particular source, it is not Damage Reduction.

Comment: Physical-damage spells exist, and at least per *Rules Compendium*, are affected by DR.

Comment: @KRyan Huh.  That contradicts [the SRD](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#damageReduction) and the PHB glossary but I suppose it's worth noting

Comment: @KRyan Where's the *RC* say that? I got *Damage reduction doesn’t reduce the damage from energy attacks, spells, spell-like abilities, and supernatural abilities* on page 41. Is there another mention elsewhere?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Huh, I’m about 80% sure—I would have said higher yesterday but nonetheless—that something says it somewhere. And even if it doesn’t, a good answer to this question shouldn’t blithely accept this oversight without comment—it’s not good or useful for the game.

Comment: @KRyan Is it possible you've conflated the *3.5* and *Pathfinder* DR rules? *Pathfinder* handles DR in what it sounds like the way you're thinking.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I’m aware Pathfinder did that, yes, but I could have sworn it came up in 3.5e before Pathfinder, too. But it’s possible that it was only in Pathfinder and I just didn’t think of it as “new” because I’d always thought it the obvious ruling regardless.

Comment: Please stop being evil, @HeyICanChan Ah, found it: *Complete Psionic* addresses this for the sake of physical-damage Metacreativity powers, saying they are subject to DR.

Comment: @heyicanchan To add here a bit, I think, any spell may say for itself, that it's damage is subject to DR. I don't know if Cloud of Knifes is useful example, as I suspect metacreativity is an analog of conjuration.

Comment: @annoyingimp O, yeah, specific trumps general, but having DR affect spells goes against the what DR is supposed to do, which was to bring to *Third Edition* a semblance of the *Can only be hit by +1 or better weapons* idea of earlier editions.